# Elasticsearch js how to upsert a document

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to do a upsert for a document. Is it currently possible to do that via nodejs elasticsearch API?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html

I looked through the API, and I could only see an upsert option for update.

Does that mean currently there aren't any way for me to upsert a document?

Thanks

Comment: till now there is no upsert method for NodeJS Elasticseach API so work around you can check the existence of document if it not exist insert it if it exist update it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set the [`doc_as_upsert`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#doc_as_upsert) parameter to `true` when calling the [`update`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_update) method to upsert a document.

```js
const response = await client.update({
  index: 'myindex',
  type: 'mytype',
  id: '1',
  body: {
    doc: {
      title: 'Updated'
    },
    doc_as_upsert: true
  }
});
```

Comment: Didn't notice that the body is the same as the update's API reference